# How to plot clustered bar chart from raw Qualtrics excel data?

Tags: powerbi, unpivot, qualtrics

My raw Qualtrics data looks something like this. Basically just 2 questions. Q1-where did you learn your tech skills from? and Q2-Do you agree with the following statement?

[image]

I want to plot clustered bar chart in Power BI that looks something like the link below. Basically, for Q1-where did you learn your tech skills from? Each cluster is a channel of learning, and within each cluster there is a standard response from not at all, to a small extent, to a moderate extent, to a great extent, entirely

[image]

I figured out I cannot plot straight from the raw Qualtrics data. However, if I unpivot just the columns for Q1, I can get the above clustered bar chart.

[image]

But here comes the problem. I have other questions with the same raw Qualtrics format. So I tried to unpivot columns for Q1 FIRST, and THEN unpivot the columns for Q2, and got the following, which does not make sense because Q1 has 4 sub-questions while Q2 has 5 sub-questions. This is like a m:m joins (if I make sense?)

[image]

So I thought maybe I could unpivot all the columns except for the Response ID column and I got this

[image]

Doing the above has several issues;

1. the number of rows gets large exponentially and imagine if I have many more questions and many more respondents, the data format just gets too large;
2. when I want to plot the clustered bar chart, I have no way to restrict the rows just to plot for Q1, or rows just to plot for Q2 etc.

I tried googling and was surprised there isn't a similar question before? given how Qualtrics is very well used for survey data.

Appreciate all your help in advance!

Comment: Don't say thank you in advance but do it after you've received help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your first step should be splitting the data from the different questions into separate tables, then "Unpivot Other Columns" but *Response ID*. You can later relate the tables in the report via this *Response ID*.
- From here creating your column charts should be a no-brainer.
- Starting with a list of question identifiers ("Q1", "Q2", ...) you can automate the splitting via a *Custom Function*
- I doubt that with *Qualtrics* Excel imports you'll come anywhere close to Power BI's data limits. However, I am surprised that they are providing such an awkward interface.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Will this work even if I have like 30+ questions? I have never added so many tables before.

Comment: Yep, careful, there seems to be a limit of 10.000 tables.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out a workaround for this. I can just plot each survey sub-question as one graph (since they are in columns anyway) and stitch them together as if they are all in the same graph without having to do pivoting/unpivoting. Something like this:

[Sample of a stitched-together graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tylC8.png)